# Windows10 Proxmox VM has no network connection after veeam bare metal restore

Tags: kvm-virtualization, windows-10, proxmox, veeam

I just performed a Veeam bare-metal(Windows10 Pro) restore to Proxmox Virtual Machine. I managed to boot the virtual machine but it has no network connection. There are 4 other VMs that have an internet connection. I tried to check the option 'inject drivers' before starting the restore but still no success. Please help. Anyone who has successfully done windows 10 bare-metal restore to Proxmox. What could be the way out of this?

Comment: Try removing the virtual network adapter and adding a new one.

Comment: You can try installing VirtIO drivers on the VM. Windows 10 doesn't have them included in the installation. https://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/Windows_VirtIO_Drivers
Another alternative is to use P2V tools to convert the physical host to VM. Might be helpful: https://www.hyper-v.io/migrating-cloud-easy-experience-choosing-p2v-converters/

Comment: Tried to install the VirtIO Was very sure this would work but no success.